# How to close the qt widget ui on a button clicked in promoted widget?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qt-designer, qtgui

I have a qt designer ui form, which has a `qwidget` at the bottom of the form. The `qwidget` has a promoted widget.

The promoted widget has a number of labels and buttons. One of the buttons is a home button. On clicking this button the user needs to close the form and open the home form.

If i use traditional methods of implementing clicked() slot and say `this->close();`, only the promoted widget will be closed.

I want the entire ui to be closed and then open the Home form. How do I go about it? Is there a call to the qt designer ui form from the promoted widget to indicate that the home pushbutton is clicked?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `SIGNAL` to your class (let's say named `close()`) and then whenever the button is pressed this SIGNAL goes off and by connecting your class to this signal you can set you form to close.
[Here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) you can find a basic tutorial on SIGNALS. If you put your code in the question I could guide you through the code as well.

Comment: well.. These are promoted widgets. It is a part of the ui. So the traditional emit signal and connecting in main ui slot does not work. I did try that earlier. On the button click i wrote emit this->home() and in main ui i connected the signal of this class to the slot gotoHome() where i indicated this->close(); It does not work.

Comment: i used the object as the base class of the promoted widget and then took the signal home() from there. This worked. Earlier I had instantiated the promoted widget class and tried to connect the emitted signal. I didnt realise the base class qwidget in the main ui form was the actual object. Thank you for helping. :)

Comment: @DmitrySazonov The problem is solved. Should I post the solution? As in the sample code?

Comment: @Giz : I'm sorry I was not online to answer to your first question. No problem :)